# How to efficiently develop and debug lists for couch db?

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I try to develop a lists view for couch db. Currently I'm using the built in tool in futon since that's the only way to actually get the code into the database engine.

Problem is that you have to use one line without line breaks, color coding or other convenient things I'm used to.

The alternative I can see is to use an external editor and for each test run I remove all line breaks from that editor and copy it to the design document.

There surely must be a better way because how I do it is silly.

Comment: I'm not really following here, you have the ability to work with temporary design documents and views and also any persisted design documents, using the editor in Futon where you have a map part and a reduce part (not talking about the "source view"). But, sure you could set someting external up and store your design docs using http requests.

Comment: The question was not regarding the map and reduce part of the design document, those Futon provide a decent tool for. I was referring to the lists part. I haven't found any way to work with those in Futons editor. And I could surely set up something external to work with this. I was just hoping such a (possibly) recurring problem would have a general solution.

Comment: Not sure what the upcoming Fauxton IDE (Futon replacement) brings. Think you could start trying it out by installing it manually http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/fauxton/install.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called erica which could help you: https://github.com/benoitc/erica

Comment: Thanks. I will give that tool a try.